# Windows 8 Metro Video App Error

Tags: windows-8

When trying to play online movie in Windows 8 Video App, it generate an error saying:

[image]

How do I change my region or any other way to prevent this error?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/use-windows-store-country-region-help

Comment: @Ramhound This is for windows store i already tried this. But it still  don't work

Comment: Your problem is connected to the Windows 8 Video App whose region is determined by the region of the Windows Store.

Comment: @Ramhound But this still not working.